# at least 1 remainder has a 1 at the 2nd decimal place

Tags: probability-distributions

Let X be >= USD 10.00 to <= USD 49.99

We distribute to 10 person unevenly with an random amount.

What value is X which will yield at least 1 person amount that ends with USD x.x1. that is the last decimal digit of the cents is 1 ?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you revise what you have written? It is not clear.

Comment: what is the highest probability of X Value that will yield the last decimal of dollars to be 1. that is ??.?1 cents. ends with 1 cent as the last decimal. any amount is ok but the last digit is 1.